# customed index with dotfill in frontmatter

Tags: indexing, front-matter

I wanted to custom my index so I used a `latex makeindex -s myfile.ist texfile.idx latex` compilation.

myfile.ist contains :

```
% 
heading_prefix "{\\bfseries\\hfil "
heading_suffix "\\hfil}\\nopagebreak\n"
headings_flag 1

% 
delim_0 "\\dotfill"
delim_1 "\\dotfill"
delim_2 "\\dotfill"
```

my TeX file contains:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
% arara: makeindex
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: on }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage[l2tabu, orthodox]{nag}  %
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\makeindex

\author{Romain}
\title{Index Book}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\frontmatter        

\chapter{Preface}
    \lipsum \index{preface}

\mainmatter         

\chapter{Intro}
    \lipsum \index{intro}

\appendix

\chapter{balala}
    \lipsum \index{annxes}


\chapter{balba}
    \lipsum \index{annxes} 

\backmatter
\chapter{epilogue}\index{epilogue}
    toto. 

    \printindex \label{index} 


\end{document}
```

And I get the error message:
`Undefined control sequence. \item preface \dotfill`

I tried to remove `delim_* "\\dotfill"` or `\index{preface}`, in both case it works. 
So index in `frontmatter` and `delim_* "\\dotfill"` is compatible ?

Comment: also might be an idea to use `\dotfill "` notice the space.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! But can you explain to me why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I tried your code LaTeX complained that `\dotfillii` was not defined. Thus I concluded that the `ii` page number from the frontmatter was added directly after the addition of the `delim_0`.

I had a look in the generated `.ind` file and found

```
\begin{theindex}
{\bfseries\hfil A\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item annxes\dotfill4, 6

  \indexspace
{\bfseries\hfil E\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item epilogue\dotfill7

  \indexspace
{\bfseries\hfil I\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item intro\dotfill2

  \indexspace
{\bfseries\hfil P\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item preface\dotfillii

\end{theindex}
```

not the expected

```
\begin{theindex}
{\bfseries\hfil A\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item annxes\dotfill 4, 6

  \indexspace
{\bfseries\hfil E\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item epilogue\dotfill 7

  \indexspace
{\bfseries\hfil I\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item intro\dotfill 2

  \indexspace
{\bfseries\hfil P\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item preface\dotfill ii

\end{theindex}
```

Adding the space was the logical conclusion.